# onClickListener issues cannot find solution

Tags: android, onclicklistener

I can't find a solution for my problem! I keep getting the error:

> onClickListener cannot be resolved to a 
>    type

Please Help!! Here is my code

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements onClickListener{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        send.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: did you try to capitalize the 'O' in OnClickListener?

Comment: It's been a few months since I did any Java, but doesn't implements mean you are going to provide the function in this class.  ie you say you implement it but I don't see it here

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this method according to your aim:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view)
{
    //....
    //....
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`onClickListener` should be like this `OnClickListener`

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    send.setOnClickListener(this);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a method like `addOnClickListener();`
and work on it like:

```
public void addOnActionListener(){
        Button send=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        send.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
        //...
        //...
```